# CAML query on sharepoint list

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have a sharepoint list with the following fields:

Product Name
Product Description
Price
Product Type

---

Product Type can be either a CD or DVD

I would like to be able to obtain all data/records on the list based on a CAML query for Product Type. Here is my CAML query:

string prodType1= "CD";
string prodType2= "DVD";

```
string camlquery = 
@"<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Products_x0020_Type'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + prodType1 + @"</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>";
```

I want to be able to bring back all data/records for product type CD. How can I acieve this with CAML, if possible. If not possible what other method would be recommended for this.

I have been scratching my head with this for a over a week now, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you verify that your CAML query in your question matches what you are using.  Currently that's not a valid query with the dangling (unclosed) FieldsRef tag.

Comment: my mistake I have ammended what the CAML query to what it should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'd suggest the [U2B CamlQuery Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx).. it's the easiest way to build your queries and saves you a lot of trouble and time...

when you finished building just go to the editor tab and copy the query (without the `<query>` tag);...

Comment: oh yea totally forgot about that :-) +1

Comment: I am inlcuding the <Query> simply becasue I would like to select the specific fields from the CAML query such as Product Name, Procuct Description. Is is possible from the above query to only select the Product Name, and Product Description? Many Thanks